# Case with no return value

Tags: scala, match

I have the following unit test:

```
FlattenArray.flatten(
    List(0, 2, List(List(2, 3), 8, List(List(100)), null, List(List(null))), -2))
    should be(List(0, 2, 2, 3, 8, 100, -2))
```

With my implementation as follow:

```
object FlattenArray {
    def flatten(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
        list match {
            case Nil => Nil
            case (x: List[Any]) :: tail => flatten(x) ::: flatten(tail)
            case x :: tail => x :: flatten(tail)
        }
    }
}
```

The test if failing because, on case Nil I should add no value to the flatten list: any suggestion on how to do so?

I could filter out from the flatten list null values: is that the correct implementation?

Comment: Have little time to answer cause exam in like 5 minutes but on first glance I think you should not be creating `List` with `null`s in it, but rather `Nil`. `null` will throw NullPointerException when you try to flatten it

Comment: @JordanCutler - No it won't.  It's just that the `null` in a list doesn't match `case Nil => Nil`

Comment: In this case you're correct it won't throw null pointer since the null is nested in a List, but if you run `List(List(1), null).flatten` it will throw NullPointer

Answer (score 5):

You can add a special case for `null :: tail` which returns `flatten(tail)`:

```
def flatten(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case null :: tail => flatten(tail)
    case (x: List[Any]) :: tail => flatten(x) ::: flatten(tail)
    case x :: tail => x :: flatten(tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was all set to answer this with the same case presented as `case x :: tail if (x == null) => flatten(tail)`  I had no idea you could just use the `null` like that.  Nice.